# How to sort array of objects alphabetically except for numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have this array:

```
sampleArray = [
  {name: 'product-2'},
  {name: 'product-15'},
  {name: 'product-3'},
  {name: 'product-10'}
]
```

I want to sort it using the property `name`, alphabetically except for numbers inside the strings.

I am using `sort` combined with `localeCompare`:

```
sampleArray.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
```

However, as `name` is a string that contains a number I am getting this:

```
sampleArray = [
  {name: 'product-10'},
  {name: 'product-15'},
  {name: 'product-2'},
  {name: 'product-3'}
]
```

I need to get it in the correct order considering the numbers as well. What would be this:

```
sampleArray = [
  {name: 'product-2'},
  {name: 'product-3'},
  {name: 'product-10'},
  {name: 'product-15'}
]
```

I know if I was working only with numbers I could do that:

```
sampleArray.sort((a,b) => a - b)
```

But that's not the case.

How can I solve this?

Comment: @zcoop98 no, I had already seen that. It gives me the same output I am getting with my code.

Comment: Yeah, I realized your question was distinct right after pulling the trigger. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You was half way, [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) accepts an option where you can use a natural sorting with strings.

```js
const
    array = [{ name: 'product-2' }, { name: 'product-15' }, { name: 'product-3' }, { name: 'product-10' }];

array.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(
    b.name,
    undefined,
    { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' }
));

console.log(array);
```